# Grouping incidents and where they happened

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, count, distinct

How do I write a query to group incidents by `year`, `block`, `primary_type`,`location_description`, `district`, and `ward`.

```
SELECT
year, block, primary_type, location,_description, district,ward
FROM `chicago_crime`
WHERE primary_type = "H******E"
```

I've tied different functions and I believe I am missing something but can't figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve that by using the GROUP BY clause, after WHERE clause.

```
SELECT
    year,
    block,
    primary_type,
    location_description,
    district,
    ward
FROM
    chicago_crime
WHERE
    primary_type = 'H******E'
GROUP BY
    year,
    block,
    primary_type,
    location_description,
    district,
    ward;
```

Comment: It worked, I kept forgetting to group by all the columns. Thanks!